# How can I see dumps of wholе HTTP packets in FreeBSD?

Tags: unix, http, freebsd, packet-sniffer

I need to see whole HTTP packets sent and recieved by an application for debugging purposes. How can this be done in command-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `tcpdump` command like:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i <interface> -s 1518 -XX -vv -n "tcp port 80"
```

You customize the command according to your needs. You can add `-w filename.pcap` to save the dump to a file. Then, you can read the dump file using `-r filename.pcap`.

Comment: You can use -s0 for no limit to the snaplen.